# Spring Boot / REST - Sample Code Terminates After Launch

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-rest

I am simply trying to run the sample code (via STS IDE as a Spring Boot App), but it simply terminates (and no errors occur).   Downloaded from git, didn't modify.

**Building a RESTful Web Service**
Sample Code : https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/
Git Repo : git clone https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-rest-service.git

**Note : The one thing I tried, put [spring-boot-starter-tomcat] in my maven dependencies and downloaded, to no avail.

> :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.4.3.RELEASE)
>
> 2017-01-09 17:33:14.942  INFO 5548 --- [           main]
>   hello.Application                        : Starting Application on
>   TDL05100504 with PID 5548
>   (C:\wm_dev\gs-rest-service\complete\target\classes started by marshw2
>   in C:\wm_dev\gs-rest-service\complete) 2017-01-09 17:33:14.946  INFO
>   5548 --- [           main] hello.Application                        :
>   No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
>   2017-01-09 17:33:15.043  INFO 5548 --- [           main]
>   s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@6dc17b83:
>   startup date [Mon Jan 09 17:33:15 EST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
>   2017-01-09 17:33:17.526  INFO 5548 --- [           main]
>   o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX
>   exposure on startup 2017-01-09 17:33:17.553  INFO 5548 --- [
>   main] hello.Application                        : Started Application
>   in 3.224 seconds (JVM running for 4.192) 2017-01-09 17:33:17.555  INFO
>   5548 --- [       Thread-1] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext :
>   Closing
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@6dc17b83:
>   startup date [Mon Jan 09 17:33:15 EST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
>   2017-01-09 17:33:17.559  INFO 5548 --- [       Thread-1]
>   o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed
>   beans on shutdown

Comment: Try downloading a spring boot example from http://start.spring.io/ and adding your code into it.

Comment: Which sample code? Questions should be self contained in here. Posting links isn't enough, but you didn't even do that.

Comment: Does the code start any WebServer or something else that has non-daemon threads which keeps the process running. Post you main method.

Comment: My apologies.   It's the main sample for Building a RESTful Web Service. https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/
git clone https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-rest-service.git

Comment: @KlausGroenbaek - No, it's just trying to expose an endpoint, and print "Hello World" back.   I have the links to the code in the question now.

Comment: I had similar problems, I changed to build using Spring Boot 2.0 with Java 1.8 and that worked for me.

Comment: can you show me pom file?

Answer (score 0):

The project will run as is, so you shouldn't need to make any changes.  Create a folder named resources under src/main.  In that folder add a file called application.properties (or application.yml if you prefer yaml).  Add a line to this file that will crank up the logging level to debug, you should get more details about what's going on.

```
src/main/resources/application.properties

logging.level.org.springframework=DEBUG
```

This is going to generate a LOT of information, but should spit out enough to show you what's up.

Comment: I cranked up the spring logging (as you suggested), but to my eye, it don't see anything suspicious.   Results are here.  http://www.nomorepasting.com/getpaste.php?pasteid=40082

Comment: Most curious.  My next suggestion would be to build the uber jar with `mvn package`, and run it on the command line via `java -jar target/gs-rest-service-0.1.0.jar`

Comment: Hi Lane,   Thx for the feedback!   I did try this, and the output (and behavior) matches what I'm seeing in STS.   One interesting thing that occurred was I had to skip the tests (mvn install -DskipTests).   

When building normally, I was getting  Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'mockMvc' - org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.

Comment: Hum, that makes me wonder if you don't have other Maven issues.  You might try removing your local maven repository and run `mvn package`, perhaps some of your local artifacts are corrupted.

Comment: Hi Lane,   Yes, solved, thx for all your help!   I had already tried using the "Force Update of Snapshots/Releases" option in STS when doing Maven Update, but it appears this may not actually work.   However, physically deleting the repo in File Explorer did do the job.

Comment: Glad to assist!

Answer (score 0):

For me, this problem was caused by corruption of my maven repository.   Using STS 3.8.3, I was trying "Force Update of Snapshots/Releases" when doing Maven Update.   This did *not* work.   However, physically deleting the repo in File Explorer (and rebuilding) did do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Change sample code as follow, it will work fine:

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.4.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```